# Какие есть библиотеки для 2D графики в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal, 3d, поиск-библиотек, 2d

Хочу написать курсач, надо сделать его на Delphi. Нужно, используя какую-то библиотеку для 2D графики (что-то простое чтобы просто к пикселям на экране обращаться), написать свой рендеринг 3D графики. По сути хотелось бы ещё и проект писать используя не стандартное создание форм, а через консольное приложение.

В общем, нужна какая-то такая библиотека, как из Pascal, но только для Delphi, для реализации моих выше описанных задач, но без использования всяких фишек Delphi по созданию форм.

P.S. Кстати OpenGL пробовал, но мне кажется это что-то слишком крупное для моих задач, мне надо что-то попроще.

Comment: Актуальные ответы на подобные вопросы в первую очередь имеет смысл искать тут: https://github.com/Fr0sT-Brutal/awesome-pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это ОС Windows, то окно вам все равно понадобится (не в консоли же вы будете ASCII рисовать?). Для рисования на Canvas подойдет что-то типа GDI или GDI+. С использованием двойной буферизации они достаточно быстры )

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/graphics32
Довольно хорошая быстрая библиотека для работы с графикой.

Как работает в реале можно посмотреть SAS Planet (программа для скачивания в offline карт).